# Android - Animate RecyclerView Item of Fragment Inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation

I am using `ViewPager` with `Fragments`. Each Fragment have a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`. Inside my `RecyclerView` adapter i have set up an animation on `onBindViewHolder`.

Problem :

As ViewPager Loads two fragments at once, the animation for second fragments gets completed even if the view is not visible

Expected output :

When someone swipe on viewPager all the RecyclerView Item should animate.

RecyclerView Adapter

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    viewHolder.getServiceImageView().setImageResource(mServices.get(position).getImageResource());
    viewHolder.getServiceNameView().setText(mServices.get(position).getServiceName());
    viewHolder.getPricePerHourView().setText(String.valueOf(mServices.get(position).getPricePerHour()));
    setAnimation(viewHolder.serviceItemContainer, position);
}

private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position)
{
    // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
    if (position > lastPosition)
    {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.fade_in);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
    }
}
```

Fragment Code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cleaning, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), SPAN_COUNT));
    mServicesAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), data);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mServicesAdapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

ViewPager adapter

```
private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
            case 1:
                return new Fragment2();
            case 2:
                return new Fragment3();
            default:
                return new Fragment4();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Can anyone suggest me how to do this?

Comment: i had this problem some month ago. it's because of viewPager, it load data when your close to next page for handle huge data with a simple way.

Comment: @Ashkan Yes, I Know this. How to solve this problem and get the expected output.

Comment: i search it for a while but i did't find the right answer. call me if you find it

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. Implement own onResumeFragment() at Activity of fragment you want to animate
2. At onResumeFragment() call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); to start animations

Comment: Yes, it does. When i need some action to work when fragment is onresume and visible i use this in Viewpager. May Be help https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/viewpager-with-detailed-fragment-lifecycle-onresumefragment-including-source-code/

Comment: i should try this, tnx.

Comment: I upvoted for the onResume & notifyDatasetchange hint , although you don't need to create your own onresume method. Just use onResume inside the desired fragment and call adapter.notifydatasetchange. That's it.